How to accurately determine if a Firestore document does not exist using StreamBuilder in Flutter?
In Flutter/Dart, using Firebase Firestore, when setting up a StreamBuilder using a Stream of DocumentSnapshot objects like this:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('user_account_status')
          .doc(userId)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) { ... }

Let's say we want to infer some fact in the case where no document truly exists at this location.
If we want to be able (in code) to definitively conclude that no document exists at this location -- that is, NOT to have a false negative due to some other issue like network state, firestore rules denying permission due to misconfiguration, etc...
Then what control flow should there be in the { ... } ?
If I understand correctly,
If there is no actual stream yet, then ConnectionState will be .waiting AND snapshot.hasData will be false, because snapshot.hasData doesn't refer to to actual data contained in firestore, but to the snapshot itself -- whether or not a stream event has been emmitted.
If there is an error (including firestore rules problems), then an snapshot.hasError will be true.
So then, does that mean that as long as we can rule out these conditions, we are left with checking snapshot.data.exists and we can trust the result?

 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance           .collection('user_account_status')           .doc(userId)           .snapshots(), DO NOT build the Stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder. See my video for details: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Thanks I learned from the video, but this is actually in a stateless widget very "early/high up" in the widget tree... so it should not be rebuilt unless an ancenstor is rebuilt.  and also whether the stream will succeed depends on whether the user is authenticated (also dependent on ancestor), so if itry to move the stream to some service class, I get confused.

Unless I misunderstand the question, this can be done in a fairly straightforward manner:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('user_account_status')
        .doc(userId)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show a loading indicator while waiting for data
      }

      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'); // Handle any errors that occur during the stream
      }

      // **ATTN** this is the case you are specifically interested in
      if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
        return Text('Document does not exist'); // Document does not exist
      }

      // If the document exists, access it here
      var documentData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

      return Text('Document exists with data: $documentData');
    },
  );
}

You can also adjust this code to do exactly what you need - it handles all(?) the possible cases, including on the wire connection.

But the snapshot not having data doesn’t necessarily mean that the document does not exist isn’t that correct?

what do you mean? What would be the case where document exists and snapshot not have it? If your DB query is correct - empty means there are no matching documents.

Oh I think i might understand the problem — you had a typo here: “if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists)” correct? You meant if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) right?

This was a while ago but seems correct to me. If you don't have that check, you can't force unwrap the snapshot.data in the second part of that || safely as well as in the line below - it relies on the check that snapshot.data is not null to get the actual document data.
